# ActiveRecord Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I update a particular field of a record in my observer with a callback **before_create** . Does this update, also trigger the callback **after_update**. ?  As in my case. This seems to be happening. I confirmed by placing debuggers in my code. Why does this happen ?

Comment: No, this shouldn't happen. before_create Is called before Base.save on new objects that haven‘t been saved yet (no record exists). Please provide some model code so that one able to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails ActiveRecord callback hierarchy](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

```
(-) save
(-) valid
(1) before_validation
(2) before_validation_on_create
(-) validate
(-) validate_on_create
(3) after_validation
(4) after_validation_on_create
(5) before_save
(6) before_create
(-) create
(7) after_create
(8) after_save
```